# Correct pronunciation of EFI

Tags: pronunciation

Outside the UK/USA people pronounce acronym **EFI** (Extensible Firmware Interface) in two different versions: ***[ɪfɪ]*** and ***[ɪ-ef-aɪ]***.

The first argue their pronunciation that **'I'**, for example, mean **'Interface'** (***[ˈɪntəfeɪs]***) and should be read as ***[ɪ]***. The second argue that the English letter **'I'** is read as ***[aɪ]***.

From the point of native English speakers, what variant is more correct?

I hope there are some rules for it and this question is not opinion-based.

Comment: Oh goodness, next thing you know we'll be talking about whether it's "sexy" or "scuzzy", and whether it's "ess-queue-ell" or "sequel"...

Comment: @SamBC, No. Information about correct pronunciation of **EFI** would be enough for me.

Comment: I was attempting to illustrate the point that there is no "correct" pronunciation, and that with a lot of technical initialisms you will find a range of pronunciations - that sometimes lead to arguments. Those referenced in my previous comments being SCSI and SQL.

Comment: In response to your edit, I'm afraid there are no rules - or rather, no single set of rules - and it is rather a matter of opinion. I pronounce it like "effie", and UEFI is "you-effie", but that doesn't make me right or anything else wrong. In general, it's a case of either pronouncing it as if it were a word, or reading out the initials.

Comment: @SamBC, pronunciation of **SCSI** and **SQL** is well-documented: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL. I look for something similar for **EFI**.

Comment: Firstly, Wikipedia isn't reliable on subjects that are matters of dispute; it has a tendency to be subject to slow edit wars that don't generate enough attention to lead to protection, or the community takes a side for no good reason. Secondly, it lists *both* pronunciations of SQL that I just gave.

Comment: @SamBC, in my situation I usually pronounce "efi" or "ifi" but my boss say "iefai". I don't want to pronounce it "iefai" at team-meetings but every time when I say "ifi" other members of our team look at me with strange faces. I hope someone answer "ifi", I'll accept his or her answer and (after removing this comment) send link to this question to my boss, and we both will say "ifi". We live outside of English-speaking countries so answer of native speaker will be valuable argument for him.

Comment: If other members of the room look at you with strange faces, than you are probably pronouncing it the wrong way within your community. See the proverb [When in Rome...](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do).

Comment: @SamBC it might be better to use IPA phonetic notation. I didn't understand what you were talking about in your comment until I read further. There is a [tool that pronounces IPA](https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/) that can help make sure the IPA sounds the way we intend. It's not perfect, but I think it is better than "scuzzy" for someone who might not be familiar with the typical pronunciations.

Comment: My grasp of IPA is pretty abysmal, though I thought *scuzzy* would be okay given that it's actually a word.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I think I need to make it little clear: we have a Russian-speaking office and therefore the pronunciation of any English term is strongly evident. Also, non-English speakers find it harder to understand English words even with minimal deviations from the pronunciation they expect to hear. When we have disagreements about this, usually someone finds a source of information about the correct pronunciation and then everyone comes to a common variant. But in the case of EFI such information was not found, so I asked a question. It's sad that it was voted down.

Comment: Do note that `/ɪ/` and `/i:/` are not the same thing. The letter *E* is pronounced `/i:/`, so the initialism *EFI* would be pronounced  `/ˌi: ef ˈaɪ/`. If you pronounce *EFI* as a word, rather than as individual letters, I think you'd end up with `/ˌi:fi/`. Regardless, I think you've gotten your point across.

Comment: @SamBC I usually have to piece my IPA together by stealing bits from dictionary definitions and piecing them together, which is why I linked that tool :)  I think it’s easy to assume it’s obvious how to pronounce words that seem common to us, but English has both regional differences in pronunciation and spellings  irregularities that make it hard to guess an intended pronunciation of an unfamiliar word. It’s not a big deal in this context, but I wanted to mention it because not attempting to use a phonetic transcription has caused confusion in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not an acronym has a "correct variant" is largely dependent on how often it's used in everyday language. **EFI, like many computer-related acronyms, has no widely accepted pronunciation** because it is only regularly used by a small number of people. Some people pronounce each individual letter (like I do) and others have their own preferred pronunciation.

Unfortunately I think you have to accept that you and your boss are going to have different opinions about how to pronounce it, because neither of you are wrong. Maybe you can make it into a joke between the two of you?

Comment: We had two pronunciations in our office for [LIFFE](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/liffe.asp). One group pronounced it  /'laɪf/ and some pronounced it /lɪ'fi/ (it's too long for most people to spell out though). No-one cared and everyone understood each other. If your boss insists on a particular pronunciation though, it's probably best to just go with that version and let the matter drop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I need to make it little clear: we have a Russian-speaking office and therefore the pronunciation of any English term is strongly evident. Also, non-English speakers find it harder to understand English words even with minimal deviations from the pronunciation they expect to hear. When we have disagreements about this, usually someone finds a source of information about the correct pronunciation and then everyone comes to a common variant. But in the case of EFI such information was not found, so I asked a question.